# Sharepoint 2013 Online Which Visual Studio 2013 Template

Tags: sharepoint-online, visual-studio-2013

I am creating a sharepoint 2013 online project from fresh in visual studio which template is the best to use?

Comment: This depends on what you want to do. Whether you want to create a sharepoint add-in or console app.

Comment: I don't really want to be amending masterpages, pagelayouts etc in designer. Therefore want to package them up in visual studio create a package and then upload and activate.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are working with SharePoint Online, your only real option is an App for SharePoint. Empty SharePoint project won't work because you can't do full trust code.

So I think the best template is an App for SharePoint, unless you are doing projects for easier tooling in VS and use some other means like CSOM to push stuff to your site, then a simple Console App template works.

This question is a bit vague on what you want to do, if you are leveragivg Azure in any way and things like that. All of these factors determine what template you start from.